# Kinvey Swift 3 KCSCustomEndpoints

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, kinvey

I converted my project to swift 3 and am having issue with the kinvey conversion. I had this before but it now gives me this error: "Cannot convert value of type '(AnyObject!, NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'KCSCustomEndpointBlock!'". How could I fix this issue?

```
KCSCustomEndpoints.callEndpoint("endpointName", params: params, completionBlock: {
            (results: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if results != nil {   
            }
        })
```

Comment: Check how `KCSCustomEndpointBlock` was defined, especially the types like results, maybe it's `Any` type

Answer (score 1):

Mitch94,

This has been escalated to the engineering team for adding Swift 3 example of invoking custom endpoint to the Kinvey documentation.

I will get back to you once I have more information on it.

Thanks,
Pranav
Kinvey Support

Comment: Thank you Pranav. Could you please let me know when your engineering team adds the swift 3 example of invoking customer endpoints?